# Short life battery

Tags: 12.04, battery

I have a Lenovo Y480 and, after install Ubuntu 12.04, the life of battery is too short, I mean, when I use the other OS, it could be have a life for almost 6 hours, and when I use Ubuntu, it have a life no more than 1.5 hours.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I came across [this website](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/improve-power-usage-battery-life-in.html) some time ago. I used TLP and saw significant improvement.

Add the PPA and install TLP using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

TLP will automatically start  upon system startup, but to avoid having to restart the system to get it running for the first time, you can start it (required only the first time) using the following command:

```
sudo tlp start
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

With the following my laptop battery gained ~2 hours starting with the most battery draining piece (the screen).

Open the terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight.
```

After you installed it run this other command:

```
xbacklight -set 5
```

If you have bluetooth and don't use it turn it off.

If you're not using WiFi turn it off too.

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower off
```

and

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower on
```

to turn it back on.

To make the processor drain less battery you can use the power saving feature:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/sched_mc_power_savings
```

Now, the hard disk spinning isn't energy-free so you could tune it to spin only when necessary. Run this to install Hdparm:

```
sudo apt-get install hdparm
```

then run this command:

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

if you see **`AdvancedPM=yes`** in there go on and run this other command to enable power saving for the hard disk:

```
hdparm -B 1 -S 12 /dev/sda
```

I think this is enough. Let me know if it helped.